# Photoshop Oil Paint filter not working

Tags: graphics-card, adobe-photoshop

I have an ATI Technologies AMD Radon R$ graphics card and I've found all parts of Photoshop 2017 working fine except the Oil Paint Filter. I get the message that my system must support OpenGL v2.0 and Shader Model 3.0 or later and then nothing happens.

Do you folks know if I can make my card make this happen or if not can anyone recommend a great card that works with all of the Photoshop Filters?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you update your drivers if you haven't already. (Let me know if you need help!)

I'm assuming you meant you have an R5 but that could be a few different cards so without knowing it's hard to say if you card should support it or not.

Otherwise, if you're looking for a new card I might suggest one of the NVidia 1000 series cards, like the 1050. However if you're on a budget even that could be a bit much, so comment back if you'd like some more suggestions - happy to assist :)